# Compose: без собственной composable-функции код работает странно

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Есть такой код:

```
    @Composable
    fun FragmentA(navController: NavController) {
        val vm = viewModel(VM::class.java)
        val a by vm.a.observeAsState("")
        val b by vm.b.observeAsState("")
        Column {
            MyRandomBox()
            MyBox(a)
            MyBox2(b)
        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun MyRandomBox() {
        Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyBox(text: String) {
        Box {
            Log.e("!!!", "box-1")
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyBox2(text: String) {
        Box {
            Log.e("!!!", "box-2")
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }


    class VM : ViewModel() {

        val a = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val b = MutableLiveData<String>()

        init {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                (0..100).forEach {
                    a.value = "a-$it"
                    delay(1000)
                    b.value = "b-$it"
                    delay(1000)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Он работает отлично: каждую секунду меняется 1 из ЛайвДат и в логи выводится только тот Box, который поменялся.
А значение в самом первом Text как создалось рандомное при старте, так и висит (заново не рандомится).

Но если чуть-чуть изменить код, а именно вот так:

```
   Column {
//    MyRandomBox()
      Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
      MyBox(a)
      MyBox2(b)
        }
```

то теперь при изменении любой из ЛайвДат, в первый Text будет заново рандомиться текст

почему если обернуть этот код в собственную `Composable-функцию` все работает как надо, а без нее нет? (словно представление заново пересоздается)

UPD

так же непонятно следующее поведение:
прокинул действие `onClick`

```
   @Composable
    fun FragmentA(navController: NavController) {
        val vm = viewModel(VM::class.java)
        val a by vm.a.observeAsState("")
        val b by vm.b.observeAsState("")
        Column {
            MyRandomBox()
            MyBox(a) {
                vm.rnd()
            }
            MyBox2(b)
        }
    }



 @Composable
    fun MyBox(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
        Box {
            Log.e("!!!", "box-1")
            Text(text = text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        onClick()
                    }
            )
        }
    }
```

`LOG`

```
10:04:12.770  E  box-1
10:04:13.771  E  box-1
10:04:13.772  E  box-2
10:04:14.786  E  box-1
10:04:15.787  E  box-1
10:04:15.790  E  box-2
10:04:16.786  E  box-1
10:04:17.786  E  box-1
10:04:17.787  E  box-2
```

когда изменяется `a` логируется `box-1`
при изменении `b` логируется `box-1` + `box-2`
но если заменить `vm.rnd()` на `Log.e()` то все будет работать как задумно.
почему так происходит?

Comment: Рекомпозиция затрагивает скоуп, где происходит чтение стейта (то есть переменных a и b ибо они стейт). Composable функции создают свои скоупы (поэтому в прошлом вопросе вы правильно сделали - выделили функцию).  Но при этом некоторые не создают скоуп ибо они inline (например Column/Row/...)

Comment: @vitidev а почему такое происходит с `Text`? он не `inline`

Comment: Как понимаю я. Text и MyRandomBox не инлайн. Но они подпадают в область рекомпозиции и значение параметра text меняется (а внутри Text оно читается, что вызывает рекомпозицию и внутри Text). Если вы в MyRandomBox добавите параметр, который будете менять и он будет читаться внутри MyRandomBox, то поведение будет как и у Text. То есть compose смотрит изменились ли значения параметров и есть ли их чтение, а потому стоит ли делать рекомпозицию во вложенных скоупах

Comment: Вам нужно почитать [Stability in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability). В общих чертах - если параметр иммутабельный или помечен как @Stable, то происходит сравнение со старым значением. Если изменилось - будет рекомпозиция. Cтрока иммутабельна, но значение меняется (UUID.randomUUID()) поэтому происходит рекомпозиция элемента использующего text.  А с нестабильными параметрами так вообще всегда будет рекомпозиция, поэтому нужно следить за этим

Comment: @vitidev, compose в данном случае не перечитывает UUID, иначе бы даже не помогло вынесение этого чтения в отдельную функцию `MyRandomBox`. Здесь просто перестраивается весь `FragmentA` и заново вызывается `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.

Comment: @h8leet Не увидел разницы между моими и вашими словами.

Comment: @vitidev, если бы значение получаемое функцией `randomUUID()` не считалось immutable, то рекомпозиция `FragmentA` пошла бы дальше и перестроила бы также и `MyRandomBox`. Вы же написали, что рекомпозиция происходит из-за того, что меняется значение `randomUUID()`. Это не совсем так, рекомпозиция `Text` запросилась бы (хоть и была бы пропущена) даже, если просто была бы константа, т.к. мы вызываем функцию `Text` с параметром и сам параметр читается именно во `FragmentA`, а не внутри `Text`. Надо избегать именно рекомпозиции фрагмента, унося чтение состояний во внутренние функции.

Comment: @h8leet Вы не читайте коменты отдельно. Они образуют единый текст. Сам `UUID.randomUUID()` не триггерит рекомпозицию ибо он не стейт, но триггерит рекомпозицию вложенных скоупов если это место было затронуто родительской рекомпозицией. И что `MyRandomBox(text=UUID.randomUUID()..` ведет себя так же как и `Text(text=`, то есть compose увидит  новое значение `text=` и будет рекомпозиция вложенного скоупа. Я без понятия что вы пытаетесь мне донести. Я лишь отметил, что если сделать  `MyRandomBox(text=UUID.randomUUID()...`, но внутри MyRandomBox не читать text, то рекомпозиции MyRandomBox не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтение состояния `a` и `b` у вас происходит внутри `Column` в момент вызова функций `MyBox` и `MyBox2`. Т.к. `Column` - inline функция, то перестраивается весь `FragmentA` и в этом же фрагменте вызывается функция получения UUID.

Если выделяется отдельная функция `MyRandomBox`, то рекомпозиция `FragmentA` её не затрагивает, т.к. у этой функции (со своим scope в котором идёт получение UUID) нет состояния, которое меняется при рекомпозиции `FragmentA`.

Если переписать чтение состояния в функцию `MyBox`, то рекомпозиции фрагмента уже не будет, будет рекомпозиция только `MyBox`.

```
/* ... */
    Column {
        Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        val textProvider = { a }
        MyBox(textProvider)
    }
/* ... */
@Composable
fun MyBox(textProvider: () -> String) {
    Box {
        Log.e("!!!", "box-1")
        Text(text = textProvider())
    }
}
```

[Подробнее](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads) (developer.android.com)

Просто для примера, чтобы понять где у функций scope, также сработает, если `MyBox` вообще не выделять в отдельную функцию и вызывать чтение внутри scope какой-нибудь не inline функции, например `Surface`:

```
Column {
    Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    Surface {
        Log.e("!!!", "box-1")
        Text(text = a)
    }
}
```

P.S.
Из-за таких неоднозначностей, я не люблю популярную функцию *by*. Предпочитаю объявлять непосредственно `State` и сразу видеть, когда читаю значение состояния.

```
val a = vm.a.observeAsState("")
val textProvider = { a.value }
MyBox(textProvider)
```

---

По поводу `onClick`:

ViewModel не считается stable классом и лямбда с вызовом нестабильного класса, не обёрнутая в `remember { }`, может создаваться заново при рекомпозиции scope в котором она создаётся (`FragmentA` у вас до сих рекомпозируется при изменениях `a` и `b`).

Если объявить отдельно лямбду вот так: `val onClick = remember { { vm.rnd() } }`
Затем использовать её вот так: `MyBox(a, onClick)`, то изменение `b` уже не будет затрагивать `MyBox`.

Также, нужно поменять `Modifier.clickable { onClick() }` на `Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick)`.
Исходный вариант обозначает, что вы создаёте новую лямбду, которая вызывает ранее созданную лямбду `onClick`. В новом варианте в модификатор просто передаётся ранее созданная лямбда.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. я обновил свой вопрос еще одни непонятным мне поведение с `onClick`. буду рад, если и это объясните.

Comment: @Wlad, попробуйте так: `val onClick = remember { { vm.rnd() } }` и передавать так: `MyBox(a, onClick)`. ViewModel не считается stable классом и лямбда с вызовом нестабильного класса, не обёрнутая в `remember { }`, может создаваться заново при рекомпозиции scope в котором она создаётся (`FragmentA` у вас до сих рекомпозируется при изменениях `a` и `b`). Ещё и вызов `clickable` у `Modifier` перепишите на `clickable(onClick)`, а то вы создаёте новую лямбду, которая вызывает уже существующую `onClick`. Если поможет, то добавлю в ответ, пока нет возможности провести эксперимент.